# Не получаеться отфильтровать список

Tags: python

на вход поступает список: values:[артикул, количество деталей,номер детали,место на складе]

```
{'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
 'range': 'test2!A3:D900',
 'values': [['9262567', '6', '4', '1'],
            ['7877495', '6', '3', '1'],
            ['7878290', '8', '6', '1'],
            ['9262567', '6', '1', '1'],
            ['9542838', '6', '5', '1'],
            ['7878291', '17', '4', '1'],
            ['6828797', '2', '2', '1'],
            ['6884800', '5', '4', '1'],
            ['7786872', '5', '1', '1'],
            ['6884800', '5', '3', '1'],
            ['6490473', '1', '1', '1'],
            ['6884799', '5', '1', '1'],
            ['7703711', '4', '1', '1'],
            ['5429128', '3', '1', '1'],
            ['6884796', '4', '1', '1'],
            ['7385029', '10', '5', '3'],
            ['9802571', '2', '1', '3'],
            ['3402596', '2', '1', '3'],
            ['5429122', '7', '2', '3'],
            ['5429122', '7', '3', '3'],
            ['7337096', '2', '2', '3'],
            ['9212949', '4', '4', '3'],
            ['5133615', '11', '4', '3'],
            ['9542840', '3', '2', '3'],
            ['9162312', '2', '1', '3'],
            ['4820848', '2', '1', '3'],
            ['2947676', '3', '1', '3'],
            ['9188723', '3', '2', '3'],
            ['5133615', '11', '1', '4'],
            ['7656249', '2', '1', '4'],
            ['3334008', '2', '1', '4'],
            ['9188730', '3', '2', '4'],
            ['4593659', '3', '1', '4'],
            ['9080723', '3', '1', '4'],
            ['4726914', '1', '1', '4'],
            ['4576747', '4', '2', '4'],
            ['3314206', '1', '1', '4'],
            ['9418345', '4', '1', '4'],
            ['3639393', '3', '3', '4'],
            ['9556986', '3', '2', '4'],
            ['9162310', '3', '1', '4'],
            ['7385031', '8', '2', '4'],
            ['7763069', '2', '1', '4'],
            ['7067231', '5', '2', '4'],
            ['7732954', '3', '3', '4'],
            ['69811218', '4', '1', '4'],
            ['4676634', '2', '2', '4'],
            ['7868967', '4', '1', '4'],
            ['5429136', '5', '2', '4'],
            ['9162310', '3', '3', '4'],
            ['9761350', '3', '2', '4'],
            ['7877508', '5', '4', '4'],
            ['7398664', '2', '1', '4'],
            ['9080717', '3', '2', '4'],
            ['5430384', '4', '1', '4'],
            ['5178679', '2', '1', '4'],
            ['5430384', '4', '1', '4'],
            ['4932527', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['4297104', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['4242353', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['4102193', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['4242352', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['4242352', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['3639393', '3', '2', '5'],
            ['4932528', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['2553754', '1', '1', '5'],
            ['7614682', '3', '2', '5'],
            ['9512228', '3', '2', '5'],
            ['9554912', '10', '8', '5'],
            ['7877508', '5', '5', '5'],
            ['9513502', '4', '2', '5'],
            ['7986940', '2', '1', '5'],
            ['7956285', '3', '1', '5'],
            ['7868968', '4', '1', '5'],
            ['9358251', '4', '2', '5'],
            ['7877508', '5', '3', '5'],
            ['7515801', '3', '2', '11'],
            ['7877495', '6', '4', '11'],
            ['5429155', '7', '5', '11'],
            ['5429136', '5', '5', '11'],
            ['9411775', '6', '3', '11'],
            ['4680576', '6', '5', '11'],
            ['9212940', '4', '3', '11'],
            ['9188720', '2', '1', '11'],
            ['7878290', '8', '8', '11'],
            ['4680576', '6', '2', '11'],
            ['7614695', '4', '2', '11'],
            ['6981218', '4', '1', '11'],
            ['3639393', '3', '1', '11'],
            ['7614695', '4', '2', '11'],
            ['7614682', '3', '1', '11'],
            ['9568155', '3', '2', '11'],
            ['3402596', '2', '1', '11'],
            ['7515801', '3', '1', '11'],
            ['9568155', '3', '1', '11'],
            ['6537387', '3', '2', '11'],
            ['9212940', '4', '2', '11'],
            ['3954321', '3', '3', '11'],
            ['9188730', '3', '2', '11'],
            ['7877495', '6', '1', '11'],
            ['5429136', '5', '5', '11'],
            ['9262566', '6', '1', '11'],
            ['5378061', '4', '2', '11'],
            ['5429150', '3', '3', '11'],
            ['7614684', '2', '1', '11'],
            ['9192308', '4', '3', '11'],
            ['7614682', '3', '2', '11'],
            ['9358251', '4', '3', '11'],
            ['9358251', '4', '2', '11'],
            ['9518292', '2', '1', '11'],
            ['9518292', '2', '1', '11'],
            ['9798124', '4', '3', '12'],
            ['9533311', '6', '4', '12'],
            ['9613035', '18', '12', '12'],
            ['9613035', '18', '7', '12'],
            ['6981217', '4', '3', '12'],
            ['7878290', '8', '3', '12'],
            ['5430383', '4', '2', '12'],
            ['9411775', '6', '4', '12'],
            ['7878291', '17', '13', '12'],
            ['9533311', '6', '4', '12'],
            ['9613035', '18', '12', '12'],
            ['7878290', '8', '7', '12'],
            ['7878291', '17', '9', '12'],
            ['9568159', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['7868967', '4', '3', '12'],
            ['7878291', '17', '5', '12'],
            ['7878291', '17', '5', '12'],
            ['7878291', '17', '12', '12'],
            ['7877499', '6', '4', '12'],
            ['9512289', '2', '1', '12'],
            ['9188720', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['9165464', '2', '1', '12'],
            ['9188720', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['7868967', '4', '3', '12'],
            ['6884799', '5', '2', '12'],
            ['2668', '6', '6', '12'],
            ['1707', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['7877499', '6', '3', '12'],
            ['9613035', '18', '11', '12'],
            ['9188720', '2', '1', '12'],
            ['5600661', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['9568155', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['9188729', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['6780172', '5', '1', '12'],
            ['7763069', '2', '1', '12'],
            ['7787117', '4', '2', '12'],
            ['6848158', '4', '1', '12'],
            ['3551618', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['7614682', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['1910803', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['5363520', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['6828799', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['7877500', '6', '5', '12'],
            ['9712732', '7', '1', '12'],
            ['5137563', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['7614682', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['7763069', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['7878290', '8', '2', '12'],
            ['5378061', '4', '4', '12'],
            ['9521421', '5', '5', '12'],
            ['7515801', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['9224538', '3', '1', '12'],
            ['9170942', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['7614682', '3', '1', '12'],
            ['9568155', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['7614682', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['7614684', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['9298598', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['7614682', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['7877500', '6', '1', '12'],
            ['9262567', '6', '5', '12'],
            ['7614688', '2', '2', '12'],
            ['2828', '4', '4', '12'],
            ['6981214', '2', '1', '12'],
            ['7385031', '8', '7', '12'],
            ['6828804', '2', '1', '12'],
            ['9613035', '18', '13', '12'],
            ['9212940', '4', '4', '12'],
            ['6981215', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['9224538', '3', '3', '12'],
            ['9411774', '2', '1', '12'],
            ['7385028', '10', '4', '12'],
            ['9329723', '8', '7', '12'],
            ['7385028', '10', '3', '12'],
            ['9554912', '10', '7', '12'],
            ['6884796', '4', '4', '12'],
            ['7877499', '6', '1', '12'],
            ['5429136', '5', '5', '12'],
            ['6537383', '4', '4', '12'],
            ['4641428', '4', '2', '12'],
            ['7614682', '3', '2', '12'],
            ['9613035', '18', '18', '12'],
            ['7878291', '17', '4', '12'],
            ['7668967', '4', '2', '12'],
            ['6537383', '4', '3', '12'],
            ['6884800', '5', '2', '12'],
            ['4593634', '4', '1', '12'],
            ['7614682', '3', '1', '12'],
            ['4593634', '4', '2', '12'],
            ['6884796', '4', '2', '13'],
            ['9411775', '6', '5', '13'],
            ['5429150', '3', '3', '13'],
            ['7656285', '3', '2', '13'],
            ['7878290', '8', '8', '13'],
            ['7877499', '6', '2', '13'],
            ['7877499', '6', '5', '13'],
            ['9554912', '10', '10', '13'],
            ['4253003', '3', '1', '13'],
            ['7878291', '17', '10', '13'],
            ['4732147', '3', '2', '13'],
            ['1307343', '2', '2', '13'],
            ['7878291', '17', '3', '13'],
            ['9329723', '8', '5', '13'],
            ['6981218', '4', '4', '13'],
            ['6981218', '4', '2', '13'],
            ['7042582', '5', '2', '13'],
            ['3551618', '2', '2', '13'],
            ['3954321', '3', '2', '13'],
            ['7878291', '17', '14', '13'],
            ['4980008', '3', '2', '13'],
            ['3635746', '3', '2', '13'],
            ['7042582', '5', '3', '13'],
            ['7877495', '6', '3', '13'],
            ['4571271', '3', '2', '13'],
            ['7868971', '2', '1', '13'],
            ['5429154', '6', '3', '13'],
            ['9613035', '18', '15', '13'],
            ['3797227', '2', '2', '13'],
            ['4593634', '4', '3', '13'],
            ['4571271', '3', '1', '13'],
            ['9315373', '2', '2', '13'],
            ['7336699', '3', '1', '13'],
            ['9518270', '4', '3', '13'],
            ['5429136', '5', '3', '13'],
            ['5429150', '3', '2', '13'],
            ['4267588', '2', '1', '13'],
            ['4267588', '2', '1', '13'],
            ['5378060', '4', '2', '13'],
            ['3402596', '2', '2', '13'],
            ['6880457', '6', '2', '13'],
            ['3402596', '2', '2', '13'],
            ['9613035', '18', '6', '14'],
            ['6622912', '3', '2', '14'],
            ['7878291', '17', '15', '14'],
            ['9271059', '6', '5', '14'],
            ['7336699', '3', '2', '14'],
            ['9613035', '18', '5', '14'],
            ['9542838', '6', '1', '14'],
            ['7877499', '6', '3', '14'],
            ['9293354', '9', '6', '14'],
            ['6780172', '5', '3', '14'],
            ['6848158', '4', '3', '14'],
            ['9262566', '6', '4', '14'],
            ['7877500', '6', '4', '14'],
            ['3805097', '8', '3', '14'],
            ['7521011', '14', '8', '14'],
            ['6884799', '5', '3', '14'],
            ['7703711', '4', '3', '14'],
            ['3805097', '8', '1', '14'],
            ['7877495', '6', '2', '14'],
            ['5429155', '7', '7', '14'],
            ['7877495', '6', '3', '14']]}
```

хочу получить список с неготовыми в формате [артикул,количество деталей,номера деталей-место на складе]

и список с готовыми в таком же формате туда попадают те артикулы у которых количество деталей допустим 4 совпадает с номерами деталей от 1 до 4

```
values = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId = sheet_id,
    range = 'test2!A3:D900',
    majorDimension='ROWS'
    ).execute()
#удаляю пробелы
for i in range(len(values['values'])):
    values['values'][i][0] = values['values'][i][0].strip()
#выводим уникальные артикулы и количество деталей
stok = values['values']
def display_unic_articul(stok):
    stok_art= []
    for i in range(len(stok)):
        stok_art.append([stok[i][0],stok[i][1]])
    stok_unic_art = []
    for i in stok_art:
        if i not in stok_unic_art:
            stok_unic_art.append(i)
    return stok_unic_art
unic_art = display_unic_articul(values['values'])

#добавляю деталь и место на складе к списку уникальных артикулов
def add_detail_and_location(unic_art,stok):

    for i in range(len(unic_art)):
        for x in range(len(stok)):
            if unic_art[i][0] == stok[x][0]:
                unic_art[i].append(str(stok[x][2]+'-'+stok[x][3]))
    return unic_art
```

на выходе получаю список [уникальный артикул,количество деталей нужных что бы собрать готовое изделие,номера деталей - их место на складе] а как из этого получить нужные мне списки я не знаю.
вот пример списка готовых:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот списка не готовых:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень интересно, но ничего непонятно. Без нормальной постановки задачи код писать бесполезно.

Comment: Извиняюсь поправил описание надеюсь стало понятнее.Первый раз задаю тут вопрос)

Comment: уберите код, не относящийся к вопросу. у вас должен быть в вопросе исходный список и код по его обработке. все остальное здесь не нужно.

Comment: алгоритм все равно не ясен. почему вы считаете только 3 детали? у вас в одном списке есть деталь №18, например. вот, артикул 9613035   - у вас несколько разных деталей лежат на одном месте не складе.

Comment: второе число  в списке это максимальное количество деталей в том случае список бы попал в готовые если бы в нем были бы детали от 1 до 18

Comment: все равно не понятно. для того же артикул 9613035  есть два абсолютно одинаковых списка... В общем, прям распишите алгоритм на конкретных примерах.

Comment: если 2 одинаковых списка значит несколько одинаковых деталей хранится на том же месте